# Reload app component on change in shared component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a main menu in my app.component.ts, and I have added a language selector shared component which works fine in all the components that use my shared module.  But now I want to localise my main menu. Since app.component does not include the shared module, when I change the language in my language selector it is not reflected in the menu.  I thought that I can put the selected language into local storage and in the app component constructor I could assign the translations to different variables and use those in the front end.  But I do not know how to trigger the app component constructor in my shared component, or if I should use that approach.

Here are the relevant parts of my app component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    template: `
    <div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['/Home']" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">{{home}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content" style="margin-top:80px;">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
    home: string;

    constructor() {
        var selectedLang = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedLang'));

        if (selectedLang === null) {

            this.home = "Home";
        }
        else {
            if (selectedLang.lang === 'fi')
            {
                this.home = "Koti";
            }
            else {
                this.home = "Home";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the relevant parts of my shared component :

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';

@Component({
    selector: 'language-selector',
    templateUrl: '../app/shared/components/language-selector.component.html'
})

export class LanguageSelectorComponent {

    languageSelectorClicked(lang: string): void {
        localStorage.setItem('selectedLang', JSON.stringify({ lang: lang }));
        this.translate.currentLang = lang;
        this.translate.use(lang);
    }

    constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    }
}
```

Can anybody help with this, or suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger a components constructor at all and especially not the one from the AppComponent. They are only called by Angulars DI when a new instance is created.

You can move the code out of the constructor to another method and call this method in the constructor and by other means that you think fits the purpose. For example a subscription to an observable of a shared service.